# where can i download touch screen interface driver?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, hp-pavilion

I have hp pavilion-360 laptop model 11-n010dx. 
the problem is touch screen stopped working and there is no any option available on control panel to enable and disable. I  have checked on device manager to update driver if outdated or have any other issue but i cant find it. 
i have tried to download the driver from HP official website and still there is no driver for touch screen.

[here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-11-n000-x360-pc-series/6796818/model/6970533) is the link where i go to download the driver..

what can i do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is either a problem with the driver, or possibly with the screen hardware. I found a post on the HP forums addressing both: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/HID-Compliant-Touch-Screen-Driver-Missing/td-p/6448367

Here's the basics:

1. See if the touchscreen works in BIOS. You can enter BIOS by rebooting the computer and pressing F10 when it is booting. If the touchscreen works here, then it's a driver issue. Download and install/repair the display drivers and BIOS utilities from the support page for your computer.
2. If the touchscreen does not work in BIOS, you have a hardware issue and will need to reach out to HP support. They should be able to replace the screen for you.

Answer (score -1):

Check whether or not there are system updates on your computer, go to Update and security > Windows Update > Check for updates. In my case, the newly added features has helped my find my touch screen interface driver.

Answer (score -2):

Might also want to look into updating the BIOS and or factory reset the device.